# Can I copy references to unmanaged memory without causing memory leaks?

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, emgucv

#### Context

I'm using the [EmguCV wrapper](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) around OpenCV.  As you can imagine, Emgu is full of classes with [`IntPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx) pointers to unmanaged memory, like [this property of the `IImage` interface](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/728cc968-ac7c-1429-43d8-dde43a037be5.htm), which is implemented by [`Mat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm), [`UMat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/54fae358-0713-57d1-9195-fd47e5c82659.htm), and [`Image<,>`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/a8929aab-99c5-79cf-385c-dcec7769fea1.htm).

I don't know if this is related, but those all also inherit from Emgu's own [`DisposableObject`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/1a248c0b-75ce-eae1-d650-521f24d4d308.htm) and [`UnmanagedObject`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/f7d6df34-2ee0-1ad2-b53f-4b95f3f7d12f.htm) abstract classes.

- I'm comfortable working in Java, Python, and Ruby whose garbage collectors are pretty smart.
- I'm comfortable working in C, where my heap arrays and structs are my own problem.

In the Java-calling-C flavored JNI native interop that I've done, arrays are explicitly extracted and converted from the JVM heap using JNI functions.  Then you can mess with the array in C, but you have to use JNI functions again to either copy the array to a Java returnable, or to an output parameter.  This isolates C memory management and Java memory management - they aren't concerned with each other.

But in the C# native interop world, I see that you can just use `IntPtr` pointers directly!  That's convenient if I want to do something clever/dangerous  with fast dereferencing and pointer arithmetic, but I'm pretty squeamish about manipulating them or even storing references to them.

## Question

If I do something like this

```
var img = new Image<RGB, byte>("filename.jpg");
IntPtr myPtr = img.Ptr;
```

Does that mess with the garbage collector for the unmanaged memory and cause memory leaks?  Or is `myPtr` just another link in the reference graph keeping `img` from being automatically disposed?

Or does it depend on the native code and its wrapper?  (Open/EmguCV in my case).

Comment: The IntPtr is managed and disposed by the GC like any int. However, GC doesn't dispose the object/memory adressed by the pointer. In your example, disposing or not  "myPtr" has no impact on "img" memory allocation.

Comment: @Graffito, thanks.  So if a class releases unmanaged memory, and `myPtr` is still pointing to that memory, then `myPtr` is a memory access fault now waiting to happen.  Right?

Comment: Yes, if you explicitely [clean up unmanaged resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), a memory fault will occur.

Comment: @Graffito, thanks again.  Hopefully someone can point me in a productive direction regarding unmanaged memory and garbage collection.